# Runinng jar application error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I made an app and exported it using eclipse: `Export -> Java/Runnable JAR file`

I chose the *Launch configuration* and *export destination* and checked *Package required libraries into generated JAR*.

When I open it in cmd using `java -jar C:\...\Desktop\name.jar`
I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
        at com.artframe.engine.main.Window.Create(Window.java:18)
        at com.artframe.engine.main.Main.main(Main.java:42)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Please don't link images with error, instead paste the  stacktrace in your post as text.

Comment: It looks like the easiest way is to include the dlls in the path of you app

Comment: Ok sorry, I will correct it